# Filter on specific value dataframe pandas/ python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I want to create a function that filter on a specific value in a column of an dataframe(
My dataframe has the follow columns and value:

| Zoekterm | High_bias |
| --- | --- |
| Man | 1 |
| Man | 1 |
| Vrouw | 1 |
| kind | 0 |

I wrote a function that filter on a specific value see below

```
Def most_likey_bias():                                                                                              
bias = data['high_bias'] == 1                                                                                         
if bias.any():                                                                                                
  print(data.loc[bias,['High_bias','Zoekterm']                                                                 
print(most_likey_bias())
```

The outcome of the table is:

| Zoekterm | High_bias |
| --- | --- |
| vrouw | 1 |
| kind | 1 |

This table gives back which "Zoekterm" has a value of 1
But because the " Zoekterm" has duplicates of the same name i want a table that gives me a count of each zoekterm
So the table that i want is:
This means a table where it counts for each "Zoekterm" how much "High bias" it has based on an specific value (1)

| Zoekterm | High_bias |
| --- | --- |
| Man | 4 |
| Vrouw | 2 |
| kind | 5 |

I tried with groupby or with count, but i don't get it. Could someone give me some tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with filtered rows and convert `Series` to DataFrame by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
def most_likey_bias():                                      
    bias = data['high_bias'] == 1                                    
    if bias.any():                                            
        return data[bias].groupby('Zoekterm').size().reset_index(name='High_bias')
```

Similar idea is aggregate `sum`:

```
def most_likey_bias():                                      
    bias = data['High_bias'] == 1                                    
    if bias.any():                                            
        return data[bias].groupby('Zoekterm')['High_bias'].sum().reset_index(name='High_bias')
```

---

```
print (most_likey_bias())
  Zoekterm  High_bias
0      Man          2
1    Vrouw          1
```

Comment: Hi jezrael i get an erorr unexpected EOF while parsing, i tried many things but it's not working: This what my code:                                                                                                                     def most_likey_bias():                                      
    bias = data['high_bias'] == 1                                    
    if bias.any():                                            
        return data[bias].groupby('Zoekterm').size().reset_index(name='High_bias')                                    print(most_likey_bias)

Comment: @LeylaElkhamlichi - Tested and for me working well. Only need call function like `print (most_likey_bias())` - `()` was missing